# jquery cycle.js pager graphics work in Safari, Firefox, Chrome and Opera but disappear in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cycle, pager

I finally got my site up and running. I am a graphic designer not a programmer so am a newby. Code-wise it may not be the prettiest but it works. If you go to the work section of my site, http://www.maryhutchisondesign.com, the pager (I used a background gif for the a and active state) function works in Safari, Chrome, Firefox and Opera but disappears in Internet Explorer. I got the the pagerAnchorBuilder line emailed to me by Mike Alsup. Is there something I am doing wrong? Here is a sample of the css and js. Also it works with image thumbnails when I copy the code from malsups advanced pager demos but in IE it shifts the positions of the main portfolio images.

```
.nav_ocn li {  
 width: 10px;  
 float: left;  
 margin: 5px;  
 list-style: none;  
 margin-left: 0px;  
}  
.nav_ocn a {  
 border: 0px solid #ccc;  
 text-decoration: none;  
 margin: -1px; 
 padding: 10px;  
 background-image: url(../images/pager.gif);  
 background-repeat: no-repeat;  
 background-position: left;  
 }
.nav_ocn a.activeSlide {  
 background-image: url(../images/pager_select.gif);  
 background-repeat: no-repeat;  
 background-position: left;  
}  
.nav_ocn a:focus { outline: none; }  

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#OCN_gallery').cycle({
        fx:     'scrollLeft', 
    next:   '#OCN_gallery',
    speed:  'fast', 
    timeout:  0,
    pause:   1,
    pager:   '.nav_ocn',

    // callback fn that creates a thumbnail to use as pager anchor 
    pagerAnchorBuilder: function() { 
        return '<li><a href="#"</a></li>'; 
    }
    });

});
```

Any help and inside would greatly be appreciated.

Thanks,

Mary

Answer (score 1):

Change

`return '<li><a href="#"</a></li>';`

to

`return '<li><a href="#"></a></li>';`

There was a missing '>' that IE doesn't handle as well as other browsers.